# What ESB product to choose?

Tags: esb

I' ve searched internet for a long time, but I still couldn' t find any information like I want. I need to compare ESB alternatives with respect to their capabilities such as CICS support, service management abilities, etc. Prices of the products are not important. Any little piece of experience will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks..

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you need for the CICS support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at some of the blogs and articles such as:

- http://www.infoq.com/articles/ESB-Integration
- http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2012/01/10/spoilt-for-choice-which-integration-framework-to-use-spring-integration-mule-esb-or-apache-camel/
- http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse

Answer (score 2):

For node.js programmers I want to self promote my open source project: https://github.com/salboaie/SwarmESB

It is a core for an ESB, but the main innovation is in how easy is to program your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Options I have explored are,

- FUSE ESB - It Was free earlier,recently acquired by RedHat. Have decent capabilities and having enterprise and some more editions(with SOA governance) .Based on Apache ServiceMix.
- MULE ESB- Mostly very similar to FUSE ESB in terms of features and capabilities.Used widely and good online suppport available on forums.
- Oracle ESB - Quiet expensive ,Feature rich.have abilities to support and get integrated well with Oracle components,like oracle BPEL,BPM,workflow etc.
- IBM Websphere ESB